# React Native authentication flows

Tags: react-native

[document authentication flow](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/#how-it-will-work)
in this document, if `isSignIn` is `true`, it will navigate to `Home`. if `isSignIn` is `false`, it will navigate to `SignIn`
what can i do if wanna change the value of `isSignIn` in the `HomeScreen`, here is my code

```
const App=()=>{
    const [isLogin, setIsLogin]=useState(false)
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            {isLogin?
                <tabStack.Navigator>
                    <tabStack.Screen name="home" component={HomeScreen}/>
                </tabStack.Navigator>
                :
                <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerTitleAlign:'center'}}>
                    <Stack.Screen name="login" component={LoginScreen} options={{headerShown:false, setIsLogin:setIsLogin}} setIsLogin={setIsLogin}/>
                    <Stack.Screen name="register" component={RegisterScreen} options={{headerShown:false}}/>
                </Stack.Navigator>
            }
        </NavigationContainer>
    )
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

how can i change `isLogin` in `LoginScreen`

Comment: You'll need to use global management state such as `Redux` or `Context API` fo this purpose!

Comment: What type of authentication are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

I use redux you'll find a complete project about authentication on my gitlab if you have any question don't hesitate .

https://gitlab.com/darksh3ll/learn-react-navigation-v5